# Filter elements that have matching data-filter and class name using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div of buttons with data-filters.

```
<div class="filters">
  <button class="selected" data-filter="all">Show All</button>
  <button data-filter="type-one">Show One</button>
  <button data-filter="type-two">Show Two</button>
  <button data-filter="type-three">Show Three</button>
</div>
```

Clicking the buttons should add a class .match to the specific li element of the list that has the same class name as the data filter of the button that is clicked.

```
<ul class="elements">
  <li class="type-one other-class">Element 1</li>
  <li class="type-two other-class">Element 2</li>
  <li class="type-three other-class">Element 3</li>
</ul>
```

The button that is clicked should also have the .selected applied only on him.

[Here is a Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/v1kt0r_a/ggdv613j/1/)

I have trouble successfully comparing the data filter and the class name of two different elements and also adding a class only to the one li and not all of them. Probably missing something very obvious. Also, I've left out my JS code, for a fresh take on this.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Without the js code (which you've intentionally left out), we don't see what did you tried until now.

Comment: Please add what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following

```
//this event handler will listen to buttons click
$("button").click(function(){
  //remove selected class from all buttons
  $("button").removeClass("selected");

  //add selected class only to clicked button
  $(this).addClass("selected");

  //get data type filter
  var dataFilter = $(this).data('filter');

  //if data filter is all show all of them
  if(dataFilter == "all") {
      $(".elements li").show();
  }
  else
  {
    //else hide all of them and show only the one with correct data filter
    $(".elements li").hide();
    $("." + dataFilter).show();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and comments, that . was the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Peasant way:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('button').removeClass('selected');
  $('li').removeClass('selected');
  if($(this).attr('data-filter') == 'all') {
    $('li').addClass('selected');
  } else {
    $('.'+$(this).attr('data-filter')).addClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  }
});
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ggdv613j/3/

Comment: This is kind of close but should li should have the class .match if the class of the li is equal to the att (data-filter) of the button. .match CSS's can be .match {background: blue;}

Comment: Sorry, I didn't actually read the requirements since you didn't post any piece of code that you've tried. It's just a 30 sec peasant answer :D

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I got it now. I've left out the JS because I've spend embarrassingly long time on this